# Chrome Custom Tabs throwing an error when chrome is not installed : No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Chrome custom tabs working fine when chrome is installed but when chrome is not installed it is throwing an error

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
intentBuilder.setShowTitle(true);
CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(activityy, intentBuilder.build(), Uri.parse(link), new WebviewFallback());
```

LogCat Error Info

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: opensource.itspr.recycler, PID: 13114
   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://www.google.com/... pkg=com.android.chrome (has extras) }
       at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1889)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1579)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3921)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3881)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4208)
       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4176)
       at android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.launchUrl(CustomTabsIntent.java:165)
       at opensource.itspr.recycler.Util.customtabs.CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(CustomTabActivityHelper.java:41)
       at opensource.itspr.recycler.HolderNews.ItemLink$1.onClick(ItemLink.java:55)
       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Error Info Image

[image]

WebViewFallback.java

```
public class WebviewFallback implements CustomTabActivityHelper.CustomTabFallback {
@Override
public void openUri(Activity activity, Uri uri) {
    Log.d("I came here", String.valueOf(uri));
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, WebViewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(WebViewActivity.EXTRA_URL, uri.toString());
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

WebViewActivity.java

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String EXTRA_URL = "extra.url";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);
    String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
    WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    setTitle(url);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do?

Comment: It should fall back to normal browser, i gave "new WebviewFallback() "

Comment: I provided WebviewFallback and WebViewActivity Code

Comment: Ok I provided an answer before your comment but it's probably not what you want. I'm not familiar with `CustomTabActivityHelper` but are you sure there is any browser installed?

Comment: @Prashanth What's the Android version? For me, when Chrome is not installed, it handles it automatically by opening Webview Tester.

Answer (score 9):

I assume your question is "How do I detect and handle Chrome not being installed?" so here you go...

The key is likely going to be [`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities (Intent intent, int flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryIntentActivities%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

> Retrieve all activities that can be performed for the given intent.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *intent* - The desired intent as per `resolveActivity()`.
>
> *flags* -  Additional option flags. The most important is `MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY`, to limit the resolution to only those activities that support the `CATEGORY_DEFAULT`. You can also set `MATCH_ALL` for preventing the filtering of the results.
>
> **Returns**
>
> A `List<ResolveInfo>` containing one entry for each matching `Activity`. These are ordered from best to worst match -- that is, the first item in the list is what is returned by `resolveActivity(Intent, int)`. If there are no matching activities, an empty list is returned.

Something like this:

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
intentBuilder.setShowTitle(true);
final Intent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
final List<ResolveInfo> customTabsApps = activityy.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(customTabsIntent, 0);

if (customTabsApps.size() > 0) {
    CustomTabActivityHelper.openCustomTab(activityy, customTabsIntent, Uri.parse(link), new WebviewFallback());
} else {
    // Chrome not installed. Display a toast or something to notify the user
}
```

Comment: But there  is WebViewFallback in CustomTabsHelper which is handling this?

Comment: @user1624194: A quick Google search leads me to some code that suggests that is what it should do. That said your stack trace seems to indicate that is not occurring and that it's trying to launch Chrome...

Comment: Found it, I haven't Declared WebViewActivity in my AndroidManifest :P, Thanks for your Time

Comment: @user1624194 lmao this is exactly what happened to me, copy and paste too much

Answer (score 0):

You have to first check for chrome whether it installed or not. This code may help you to check whether app installed or not.

```
isAppInstalled("com.android.chrome");
private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
boolean installed = false;
try {
   pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
   installed = true;
} catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
   installed = false;
}
return installed;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help if Chrome is installed but disabled